# For two algebraically closed fields, one is isomorphic to a subfield of the other

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

I am aware that there is a result saying that if $L_1, L_2$ are two algebraically closed fields of the same characteristic, then either $L_1$ is isomorphic to the subfield of $L_2$, or $L_2$ is isomorphic to a subfield of $L_1$.

I am unsure however of how to prove this result. I am quite surprised that this is true, because I feel like these algebraic subfields can be so large that there's no reason why their structures have to have similarities like this. Could anyone offer some insight please?

Comment: The idea in the solutions below is that, up to isomorphism, an algebraically closed field is determined its characteristic and its transcendence degree over the prime subfield, which is the cardinality of any transcendence basis over the prime subfield. It's conceptually similar to dimension of a vector space, i.e. for any two vector spaces over the same field, the one of smaller dimension embeds in the other. One other point, the result in OP may need (some version of) the axiom of choice to be able to compare cardinalities of the transcendence bases.

Comment: ... or even for transcendence bases to exist.

Answer (score 3):

Let $k$ be the prime field of the common characteristic of $L_1$ and $L_2$, let $B_1$ be a transcendence basis for $L_1$ over $k$, and let $B_2$ be a transcendence basis for $L_2$ over $k$.  Then either $|B_1|\leq |B_2|$ or $|B_2|\leq |B_1|$; suppose WLOG that $|B_1|\leq |B_2|$.  Choose an injection $i:B_1\to B_2$; this then gives a homomorphism $j:k(B_1)\to k(B_2)\subset L_2$.  Since $L_1$ is algebraic over $k(B_1)$ and $L_2$ is algebraically closed, we can extend $j$ to a homomorphism $L_1\to L_2$.  Thus $L_1$ embeds in $L_2$.

Answer (score 2):

What follows is meant to illuminate the intuition, and is neither a proof nor entirely formally accurate.

Both fields contain the same copy of either the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ or of $\mathbb{F}_p$ depending on what the characteristic is. This is a straightforward consequence of the fact that the smallest subfield of any field is one of the $\mathbb F_p$ or is $\mathbb Q$.

All of the other elements of $L_1$ and $L_2$ are transcendental, by definition. However, all transcendental elements “look the same.” From an algebraic point of view, transcendental numbers interact with algebraic numbers just like formal symbols. For an illustrative example, we have: $$\mathbb R(x)\cong {\mathbb R(\pi)}\cong{\mathbb R(e)}$$

We can take an algebraically closed field, add a transcendental element, close under field operations, close under polynomials, and what we get back is another algebraically closed field. However, it doesn’t matter which element we added, any field obtained this way is isomorphic to every other one by the above equation.

If you iterate this process, you can construct any algebraically closed field. The process is straightforward:

> Let $A$ be an algebraically closed field whose smallest sub field is $F$. Let $F_0=\overline{F}$. To construct $F_{s(\alpha)}$, pick any element in $A\setminus F_{\alpha}$ and call it $a$. We define $F_{s(\alpha)}=\overline{F_\alpha(a)}$. For limit ordinals, we define $F_\beta=\cup_{\alpha<\beta} F_\alpha$. It can be proven that every element of $A$ will be eventually added by this process, and so for some $\gamma$ we have that $A=F_\gamma$. Therefore every algebraically closed field has this form.

So all of the algebraically closed fields look the same, it just matters how many times we do this procedure. That’s what determines which one is isomorphic to a subset of the other.

Comment: I think maybe you want "algebraic closure of Q" rather than C, as the minimal algebraically closed field in characteristic 0. For instance, the given algebraically closed fields could have finite or countable transcendence degrees over Q, which would make them "smaller" than C.

Comment: @Ned Thank you, I fixed that.

Comment: Could you explain the start of paragraph 3, "all other elements of $L_1$ and $L_2$ are transcendental" (I assume meaning transcendental over the prime field?). Isn't it still possible for there to be elements that are algebraic over the prime field? Sorry if I have misunderstood I just started learning this concept. Thanks!

Comment: @eatfood Yes, I mean transcendental over the prime field. When I say "all other elements" I am contrasting with the elements of the algebraic closure of the prime field (discussed in the previous paragraph) and so I am exclusively referring to transcendental numbers over the prime field.